# Creating a slider with a menu bar - The heading as a link isn't aligning up correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you're all well.
I am using a code that I took from Codepen, many may come across this before, I am trying to use this code as a navigation menu with the text as a link to the section/page. The text isn't aligning correctly. Please bear in mind, that I am still new to HTML and CSS and exploring code to create usable websites. I am aware that the text container will need a anchor link for it to become a menu - this is not the issue. I really appreciate your time.

Code:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="bespoke furniture" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="GSP Furniture" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="GSP Furniture" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://gspfurniture.com/" />
    <title>GSP Furniture | Tailor Made Furniture</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <nav class="split-slideshow">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="item">
            <img
              src="https://themegoods-cdn-pzbycso8wng.stackpathdns.com/dotlife/demo/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/group-of-high-school-students-with-female-teacher-X8D9B7H.jpg"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img
              src="https://themegoods-cdn-pzbycso8wng.stackpathdns.com/dotlife/demo/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/friends-studying-together-PREVX3X.jpg"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img
              src="https://themegoods-cdn-pzbycso8wng.stackpathdns.com/dotlife/demo/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/rear-view-of-male-high-school-teacher-standing-at-YQ95J8T.jpg"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img
              src="https://themegoods-cdn-pzbycso8wng.stackpathdns.com/dotlife/demo/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/busy-woman-working-with-her-laptop-PQ9KULX.jpg"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slideshow-text">
        <div class="item">About us</div>
        <div class="item">Our Work</div>
        <div class="item">Testimonial</div>
        <div class="item">Contact us</div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- partial -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./js/jsScript.js"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
    


CSS:
```

/* Import and merge normalized.css stylesheet*/
@import "./normalize.css";

```
/* Root Color for the website */
:root {
  /* Declaring a variable */
  --color-headings: #020431;
  --color-primary: #d0aa41;
}

/* HTML Page */
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* by default html font-size is 16px */
  /* 62.5% of 16px = 10px */
  font-size: 62.5%;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: Inter, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

/* Navigation */

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow .slider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slideshow .slider * {
  outline: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item .text {
  display: none;
}
.slideshow .slider .item img {
  min-width: 101%;
  max-height: 70vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.slideshow .slick-dots {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: auto;
  color: var(--color-headings);
  display: block;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li button {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in;
}

.slideshow .slick-dots li button:hover {
  transform: translateX(-0.5rem);
}

.slideshow .slick-dots li button:before {
  content: "";
  background: var(--color-primary);
  color: var(--color-primary);
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.slideshow .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow.slideshow-right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50vw;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.slideshow.slideshow-right .slider {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.slideshow-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slideshow-text {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

JS:
//Slideshow slider

```
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'), maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length, dragging = false, tracking,rightTracking;

$sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
  $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');
$('.slideshow-left').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
  } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
  } else {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
  }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
  dragging = true;
  tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
  tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
  rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
  rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
  if (dragging) {
    newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
    newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
    diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
    $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
  }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
  dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 950,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
  initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});
$('.slideshow-text').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 900,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: can anyone help with this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `margin-top:30px;` to the CSS class `slideshow-text`.

Updated the CSS class

```
.slideshow-text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   z-index: 100;
   font-size: 80px;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
   pointer-events: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 20px;
   line-height: 0.8;
   margin-top:30px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slideshow-text {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
  }
}
```

[image]
**CSS Margin:**

The CSS `margin` properties are used to create space around elements, outside of any defined borders.

With CSS, you have full control over the margins. There are properties for setting the margin for each side of an element (top, right, bottom, and left).

CSS has properties for specifying the `margin` for each side of an element:

- margin-top
- margin-right
- margin-bottom
- margin-left

**iPhone SE screenshot:**
[image: iPhone SE]
**Moto G4 screenshot:**
[image: Moto G4]
[DEMO Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/qm8fk1bp/5/)

Comment: Thank you sir, when the screen size is decreased when using crome dev tool, the demo doesn't work, unless if I am missing something. I really thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @HimatVarsani I updated the media query and attached the screenshots for smaller size. `@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slideshow-text {
      font-size: 40px;
      letter-spacing: normal;
    }
  }` Please check the code and let me know. Thank you. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you @jebasithan, this is working now, thank you again.

Comment: @HimatVarsani If my answer helps you and working for you, can you accept the answer and give a thumbs up!. Thank you.

Comment: yes i would like to accept your answer and give you a thumbs up, how do you do that on this platform, I’m still fairly new to here. Thank you.

Comment: @HimatVarsani In my answer left side you can see the `zero value` with `up` and `down` arrow below that you can see the `tick` icon to accept the answer. Pressing `up arrow` will gives a thumbs up. Hope you got it! Thank you.